PowerShell Generic List .Where() performance with variable expansion from higher scope
Given a hashtable called $derivedValues, and a variable that requires variable expansion, I am seeing some interesting performance issues.
Given:
$rule.opnd1 = 'uninstallString'
$rule.opnd2 = 'MsiExec.exe /X$($_.keyGUID)'
$filteredKeys.Where({$_.($rule.opnd1) -eq $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($rule.opnd2)})

I get good performance. A few thousandths of a second. But when the variables to be expanded aren't $_ such as
$rule.opnd1 = 'displayName'
$rule.opnd2 = '$($derivedValues.displayName)'

performance is really bad. Easily approaching half a second. I am assuming it relates to referencing the $derivedValues that is in the "parent" scope if you will, as compared to $_ which is defined within the scope of the closure by definition.
What I am wondering is, is there a way to actually pass the $derivedValues variable into the closure so that the variable expansion is always local scope? And if so, might this improve performance? It's a weird scenario I know, so if there is a way but no one knows if it will help because no one has ever needed to do such a thing, well, I'll report back. :)
EDIT: To provide repeatable code, I have this,
$localMachineHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, 0)
$collectUninstallPaths = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
$collectUninstallPaths.Add('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')
$collectUninstallPaths.Add('SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')

$rawUninstallKeys = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Hashtable]]::new()

function Get-PxUninstallKey {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$Path
    )

    function TrimAfterNull {
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$String
        )

        return $String -replace '\0.*' # NUL and everything after
    }

    $returnUninstallKey = [Ordered]@{
        displayName = 'DisplayName'
        displayVersion = 'DisplayVersion'
        installSource = 'InstallSource'
        publisher = 'Publisher'
        quietUninstallString = 'QuietUninstallString'
        uninstallParam = 'UninstallParam'
        uninstallPath = 'UninstallPath'
        uninstallString = 'UninstallString'
        installDate = 'InstallDate'
        keyID = '$keyID'
        keyName = '$keyName'
        keyGUID = '$keyGUID'
        keyPath = '$keyPath'
        architecture = '$architecture'
    } 

    try {
        $uninstallKey = Get-Item $Path -errorAction:Stop
    } catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
        throw "Bad Key path: $Path"
    } 
    try { # only collect keys with a DisplayName
        [Void](Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path:$Path -Name:'DisplayName' -errorAction:Stop)
    } catch [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] {
        $uninstallKey = $Null
    }

    if ($uninstallKey) {
        $derivedValues = @{}
        $keyName = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($uninstallKey.Name)
        $derivedValues.Add('keyPath', $uninstallKey.Name)
        if ($Path -notLike '*Wow6432Node*') {
            $derivedValues.Add('architecture', 'x64') 
        } else {
            $derivedValues.Add('architecture', 'x32') 
        }
        $derivedValues.Add('keyID', "$($derivedValues.architecture)\$keyName")
        if (($keyName -match '^{[A-F0-9]{8}-([A-F0-9]{4}-){3}[A-F0-9]{12}}$')) { 
            $derivedValues.Add('keyGUID', $keyName)
            $derivedValues.Add('keyName', $Null)
        } else {
            $derivedValues.Add('keyGUID', $Null)  
            $derivedValues.Add('keyName', $keyName)
        }
        
        foreach ($propertyName in @($returnUninstallKey.Keys)) {
            if ($returnUninstallKey.$propertyName.StartsWith('$')) {
                if ($derivedValues.ContainsKey($propertyName)) {
                    $returnUninstallKey.$propertyName = $derivedValues.$propertyName
                } else {
                    throw "Property not found in Derived Values: $propertyName"
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    $value = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path:$Path -Name:$propertyName
                    $returnUninstallKey.$propertyName = TrimAfterNull $value
                } catch {
                    $returnUninstallKey.$propertyName = $Null
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $returnUninstallKey = $Null
    }
    
    return $returnUninstallKey
}


foreach ($uninstallPath in $collectUninstallPaths) {
    foreach ($uninstallKeyName in $localMachineHive.OpenSubKey($uninstallPath).GetSubKeyNames() | Sort-Object) {
        $Path = "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\$uninstallPath\$uninstallKeyName"
        if ($validKey = Get-PxUninstallKey -Path:$Path) {
            $rawUninstallKeys.Add($validKey)
        }
    }
}

$derivedValues = @{
    displayName = 'Revit 2023'
}
$opnd2='$($derivedValues.displayName)'


(Measure-Command{
$byWhere = $rawUninstallKeys.Where({$_.displayName -eq $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($opnd2)})
}).totalmilliseconds
$byWhere.Count

(Measure-Command{
$byLoop = [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]]::new()
foreach ($key in $rawUninstallKeys) {
    if ($key.displayName -eq $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($opnd2)) {
        $byLoop.Add($key)
    }
}
}).totalmilliseconds
$byLoop.Count

With 169 uninstall keys in my collection, I am getting broadly similar numbers. When I ran both approaches three times I got this. Just by eye that looks like the averages are pretty close.
428.541
347.1521
328.2296
419.0719
328.9687
305.9063

Using InvokeWithContext and a foreach loop instead of .Where will most likely be faster than what you're doing right now

The thing is $rule.opnd2 then contains other variables that need expanded. I know the loop is supposed to be faster, but that doesn't seem to be my experience, so I am trying to profile performance of both approaches to see if I can improve things.

is opnd1 always a string that you later on reference as a property for $_ ?

Also please add the expression that you want to evaluate in the 2nd example (the slow one)

The expression is exactly the same. The only thing that changes are the values of two operands. That said, I did manage to get a VERY bare bones comparison, and it looks like it may be that iterating over the data set I have takes .3 seconds, no matter how I do it. This would be the first time in my experience that a native PowerShell approach was just as fast as a .NET approach, but in going through this exercise I have noticed some other optimizations I can do, so I'll have to implement that using a Loop and see what I get. Though I am curious about InvokeWithContext.

Why is it important to keep re-evaluating the second operand? The value doesn't change in between comparisons...

EDIT
Looking at the last update in your question, I see no benefit in using .Where and $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString in this case other than making your script slower. You could just use a loop with a filtering condition (this is as fast as it gets for filtering a collection in PowerShell):
$derivedValues = @{
    displayName = 'Revit 2023'
}
$opnd2 = $derivedValues['displayName']

$foundKeys = foreach ($key in $rawUninstallKeys) {
    if ($key.displayName -eq $opnd2) {
        $key
        # add `break` here if you want to stop as soon as a value is found
    }
}

If, for some unknown reason, you must evaluate the condition in a scriptblock expression then see the next section of this answer.

Looking for variables outside the closure is expensive as you have stated, you can probably use ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext here to pass-in the variable to be evaluated by the comparison expression scriptblock. This method allows optimization if there is no look-up in the caller's scope (uses useLocalScope: true).
Sharing an example before to show how it would work using sample object:
# supposing this object is `$_`
$inputObject = [pscustomobject]@{ displayName = 'test' }
# this object would be the value of `opnd2`
$derivedValues = [pscustomobject]@{ displayName = 'test' }
# example object of what `$rule` would be
$rule = [pscustomobject]@{ opnd1 = 'displayName' }
# define the variables passed-in to the expression
$variables = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psvariable]]@(
    [psvariable]::new('_', $inputObject)
    [psvariable]::new('rule', $rule)
    [psvariable]::new('derivedValues', $derivedValues))
# define the comparison expression
$expression = { $_.($rule.opnd1) -eq $derivedValues.displayName }
# evaluate it with the context
$expression.InvokeWithContext($null, $variables)[0]

The above shows that the comparison $_.($rule.opnd1) -eq $derivedValues.displayName evaluates to true with the passed-in variables.
The next step to further improve performance is to use a foreach loop with an if condition instead of .Where which by itself is pretty slow. With the foreach loop, instead of passing-in $_ to the context, I'll be using $key in this example:
# supposing this object is `$filteredKeys`
$filteredKeys = 0..10 | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ displayName = $_ } }
# this object would be the value of `opnd2`
$derivedValues = [pscustomobject]@{ displayName = 5 }
# example object of what `$rule` would be
$rule = [pscustomobject]@{ opnd1 = 'displayName' }
# define the variables passed-in to the expression
$variables = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psvariable]]@(
    [psvariable]::new('key', $null)
    [psvariable]::new('rule', $rule)
    [psvariable]::new('derivedValues', $derivedValues))
# define the comparison expression
$expression = { $key.($rule.opnd1) -eq $derivedValues.displayName }

foreach ($key in $filteredKeys) {
    # Gets the first `psvariable` and sets the value to the current item in the loop
    $variables[0].Value = $key
    if ($expression.InvokeWithContext($null, $variables)[0]) {
        $key
    }
}

# Outputs:
#
# displayName
# -----------
#           5


So, I am curious now if there is any value in using a Scriptblock at all. As you see in my revised post, when I use a loop I can just use a conditional. I further refined that, to run the two tests 10 times and average the results, and the loop is around 1-2% faster, which to me is a wash.

@Gordon using a scriptblock where? there is no value in using a scriptblock if you need efficiency if that's your question

@Gordon I added an update to the top of my answer. Really don't understand what is your objective or why the scriptblock is needed

the script block came about because I was getting really bad performance and in my experience native PowerShell solutions are slower, often a LOT slower, than .NET solutions, so I started looking at using .Where() which requires a scriptblock. As it turns out where .Where() isn't any faster than PS ForEach but in the process of getting .Where() working somewhat I have identified a couple of other optimizations that do make a difference. And they work with ForEach.

@Gordon try this https://gist.github.com/santisq/f1b59dfd51e0a359f733080c6c32369b#file-filteringcollection-ps1
